# Run cucumber by right clicking on it in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to simplify the way we run cucumbers. We have a runner for each folder and we always change the runner in a run configuration that has some VM options set.
I can right click on a feature, select "Run feature :" but it doesn't run successfully without the parameters from the run configuration (one of them runs the tests with an in memory database for example)

Is there anyway I can add a default configuration so I can run them directly?

Answer (score 1):

Run -> Edit Configurations

In the left-hand panel, there is a category called defaults. You can set the defaults to cucumber there. However, note that you might have to delete your previously existing configurations to get this to work with files you've already tried. They usually appear in a faded gray.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could also add a runner class, which can run (a subset of) your tests from a testing framework. You can provide @CucumberOptions in this runner.